# Can Cardio/strength training improve "stamina" for long study periods?

Tags: running, muscle, cardio, strength-training, stamina

Not being a native speaker, I am not sure whether the word "stamina" is proper. I hope you understand what I mean.

My goal is to improve the stamina for study. I want to be spending more time on studying not being exhausted or losing concentration. It would be better if I can sleep less. Many people around me claim that I need to do exercise for that. I have no idea if that's true, but I'm going to try it anyway.

According to my understanding, roughly there are two types of exercise: cardio and strength training. And it seems that doing one type of exercise can cause a negative effect on the other. For instance, they say long distance running destroys your muscle.

I am going to try both running and weight training, and I want to know on which I should spend more time for my purpose. Is there any research on this topic? Or could you share your personal experience?

Answer (score 3):

> For instance, they say long distance running destroys your muscle.

As a new person to fitness, forget about it. Yes running 20-40km in one session might deplete your levels and burn off muscle, but for most people, this doesn't apply at all.

> I am going to try both running and weight training, and I want to know on which I should spend more time for my purpose.

Do both, and see what you enjoy? Something inbetween could be doing a bodyweight workout before/after running and incorporate both. Just remember to start slow.

Comment: `Yes running 20-40km weekly might deplete your levels and burn off muscle` , What sources do you base yourself on? I run 50km+ a week and i still have quite a muscular body (off course i do other training besides running too).

Comment: I think I phrased myself poorly. I meant doing 20-40 km in a single session, not total weekly accumulated. I run about 20km a week in total myself(5km x 4).

Comment: Perhaps edit the response, because now its a bit confusing. +1 for the answer though.

Comment: This does not answer to the question " does exercise improve with concentration on other tasks? ".

Comment: Nope, but it challenges the claim "For instance, they say long distance running destroys your muscle." and provides a more in-depth understanding of it.

Answer (score 1):

I run for 10-30 minutes daily. There are too many studies that point out how cardio boosts brain power and releases endorphins. Here's my personal experience:

1) It helps me avoid being sleepy in the afternoon.

2) It helps with another activity that requires alertness / stamina: Whenever I go on a long car drive (5 to 8+ hours), I get up bit early to run/jog for 20-30 minutes in the morning before my drive. When I do this, I arrive at the destination without much strain. On the other hand, if I don't do this, I arrive at my destination totally exhausted and not in a position to do any further activity for that day.

3) Helps me sleep better at night and feel rested in the morning.

Comment: +1 Because I also think that cardio is more suitable to improve concentration and brain function, and doing sports outside in fresh air is very stimulating indeed. Weight lifting in the other hand is rather dull and making you mentally tired...